# JWT Tokens and Firebase Auth Tokens are perfect for security?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I've been searching how to make a public http request secure and all the answers are to use a token like JWT.

But from what I understand, the reason for using this token. Isn't this to prevent someone from trying to modify someone else's data other than your own?

Then user can still manipulate his own data using his own tokens. Because when you first connect to the app, you will get a token from the server.

That person can modify his or her data at any time. Wouldn't he be able to modify the game points he has at any time? (I actually saw an answer in another answer (which said to make that http call only available once after the game is over))

but if he knows the jwt token and http request url then he still can modify right??

Are JWT tokens used in the worst case to keep someone else's data from being touched?

Comment: The one and only purpose of tokens is to prove someones identity, ie to prove to the API that you are user `hoapol`. What that specific user is allowed to do or not to do is completely up to the business logic and doesn't have anything to do with tokens ...

Comment: @derpirscher So, then why prove your identity? Isn't that a necessary element to configure the mechanism to be able to modify only one's own? In other words, The server only checks whether the user has signed up for the app or not, and if so, can the user freely allow hacking and data modification? (if his own data)

Comment: for instance, they change their arguments value slightly for rest api

Comment: You can still validate those arguments in your backend. I'm not sure why do you have an API that let's user change their game points, but you can sure check if the points in API are valid or not?

Comment: @Dharmaraj back to the bottoms, I`m curious why do we need tokens, Do you use it when you want the user to modify only their own data? (but they may still can manipulate arguments for http request if he trying to change his own data because he has valid tokens)

Comment: If you rely on user IDs, it's easier for anyone to impersonate others. Like I know your Stackoverflow user ID is `18516895` but I cannot just use that to post answers on your behalf. I'll need any tokens/cookies stackoverflow users and so. These tokens can be verified at backend to ensure they were not signed by anyone else and also expire after a certain duration. https://jwt.io/introduction

Comment: @Dharmaraj So if u know my current Stack Overflow JWT tokens, and know the post url, you can answer using my tokens? and able to change my nick name also?

Comment: I'm not totally sure about Stackoverflow's auth, I was referring to basic JWT authentication. Like if anyone gets your token (Firebase ID Token for example), they can sue your account as long as the token is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The JWT token is just used identify the user making API request and checking whether the user is authorized to make that request. When you decode a JWT (Firebase Auth's JWT for this example), you can read user's UID and custom claims, etc.

Passing user ID directly in API requests is not a good idea because they are usually public (e.g. your Stackoverflow ID is 18516895) and easy to guess. So I can just try passing some random numbers/string and might be able to make requests on behalf of someone else. So JWTs are mostly used for Authorization and Information Exchange.

Also checkout: [Introduction to JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/introduction)

---

> But suddenly I want to raise my stack overflow score. Then just checking the token is not enough for server I guess. right? How do you prevent in this case?

Allowing users to update their score doesn't seem to be a good idea. Instead the score should be done totally on back-end and can be triggered by any action such as user winning the game.

Take Stackoverflow for example, only the person who has asked the question can mark any of the answers as accepted. This is authorization. No one else is allowed to do so. After an answer is accepted, the system updated answerer's score (reputation), so there is no API request that is made from client side to increase score.

The flow could be like:

1. Questioner accepts an answer
2. Verify JWT, marked as accepted if owner of question
3. Increase score (reputation) of answerer

---

Adding to another case of single player game Tetris where the user directly needs to update server for a win and earn points as discussed in comments, it might be best to send every move to server and run all game win logic on backend instead of checking for win on client and letting users hit a */win* API over and over again. If the game is completed, then credit points to user if won.

Comment: Thanks for attention, yah your example is so good and seems almost perfect but in this case, This is a case in which the trigger cannot be modified because the initial occurrence of the trigger occurs not from oneself, but from another person. (good logic) But there seems to be an ambiguous case somewhere. For example) Assume there is a Tetris game that can only be played solo, and the score is stored on the server. In this case, you must unconditionally modify your own information (there is no other trigger).

Comment: The best way to bypass is only one. Rather than raising the score, it tells the server that you have won the game. But this time, there is no API to continuously increase the score. Instead, it continues to call the API for winning the game. So the result is the same. Yes, that's right. You can also do defensive tricks using time by saving the time the user won the last game. (but doesn't completely prevent it anyway)

Comment: So what I'm trying to say is that when it comes to modifying your information, (User's own data modification) there is no perfect security method other than monitoring. JWT is also useless here. Do I make sense logically? JWT is only used when you want to prevent other people from modifying your information.

Comment: @hoapol you can extend this with your logic. But even for such case as you mentioned, you call an APi to mark a game as win instead of letting user increase their points. Now it's obviously difficult to prevent user from calling the win again and again. For the given Tetris example, you can send each move to server, then server will check if the game has completed or not, if user won then increase score else run any other logic.

Comment: Essentially, don't compute any result or check if user has won game on client side. Send every move to backend and run all logic there. Checkout [this video](https://youtu.be/eWj6dxfN63g) from Firebase for another tic tac toe example.

Comment: That's right, it seems like we have no choice but to keep stacking up very tricky and tricky logic to make it almost impossible (I think that's the best thing and only the way) BTW What do you call these tricky logic methods? Keywords or terms (I will try to search for them) Time tricks will reduce the number of cases, and there may be other good tricks out there (all of them will not give you a perfect solution, but it will make it hard for hackers)

Comment: @hoapol have I missed anything from the question to answer?